# Keeping the currency formatted JQgrid cell blank without default value if no is value returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, currency, jqgrid-formatter

once of the the cells in my jqgrid is currency formatted with the 
**formatoptions:{decimalSeparator:".", thousandsSeparator: ",", decimalPlaces: 2, prefix: "$ ",defaultValue:''}**

This is the case when I have a value for it 
But in cases where I don't have a value to that particular field Grid by default takes **$0.00** 
I would like to keep it blank instead of filling with a default value ie **$0.00**

How can I do that?
After looking up some question I went with the custom formatter

```
if (cellValue != 0.00) 


  {

    return $.fmatter.util.NumberFormat(closingAmount, $.jgrid.formatter.currency);

}
else
{

    return "";
}
```

in this case how can I add **$** as the prefix?? and ofcourse sorting on this field is not working.
Looking forward to a quick help and fix from someone 
thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.fn.fmatter.call(this, "currency", cellValue, options)` inside of custom formatter instead of the usage of `$.fmatter.util.NumberFormat`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365779/jqgrid-showcol-hidecol-not-working-after-sorting[link]
Could you help me with this??? @Oleg