# Sorting not working in Jqgrid after using a custom formatter

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I'm using jqgrid with datatype as json and value retrieving from another url,

```
     colModel: [
    { name: "Details", width: 200,classes: 'pointer wrap',sortable: false,
         formatter: function myFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
         number=rowObject.properties.number;
         name= rowObject.properties.shortName;
          fullDetails= '<strong> '+name+ '</strong> </br>[<a id="pointer"  title="Click to  search" href= http://google.com/search?search='+number+' target='+number+'>'+number+'</a>]';
         return fullDetails;

         }
        },
   { name:"name",jsonmap: "properties.shortName", width: 200,classes: 'pointer wrap',hidden:true},
    {name:"number", jsonmap: "properties.number", width: 50 ,sortable: true,hidden:true},
    { name:"date",jsonmap: "properties.date", width: 80,hidden :false}

 ],
    pager: "#pager",
    //rowNum: 20,
    rowNum: 100,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    sortname: "matter",
    sortorder: 'asc',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    loadonce : true,
    autoencode: true,
    height:'auto',
    hidegrid: false,

    caption: "Details",
    jsonReader : {
        repeatitems: false,

        root: "properties"

       }
```

Loading works fine 
But after clicking the column header to sort it

**TypeError: rowObject.properties is undefined 
number=rowObject.properties.number;** is shown 
What could have possibly gone wrong ?
What could be the fix ?
Below given is the sample data

```
             [
                {"properties":
                   {"date":1409327760,"name":"agent M","number":"4117859","shortName":"AM"},"children":null,"valId":"225","objectType":"VAL"},
                {"properties":
                    {"date":14093278860,"name":"agent x","number":"97893783","shortName":"AX"},"children":null,"valId":"191","objectType":"VAL"}
        ]
```

Comment: sorry I missed that 
I'm extremely sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should don't use column names like `name: "properties.number"` and so on. You should look at the value of `name` property like on the value which will be used as the name of variable (or the name of the property) and the part of the value of `id` attribute.

The line `jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'local'});` inside of `loadComplete` is typically an error. If you load the data from the server and uses `datatype: "json"` then you should use `loadonce: true` instead.

You don't posted `datatype` which you used and don't posted an example (2 rows of input data would be enough) of input data. The value `repeatitems: true` of `jsonReader` seems suspected. Nevertheless I could suppose that you can use `jsonmap` attribute for reading of *original* data (returned from the server):

```js
{ name: "number", jsonmap: "properties.number", width: 50, hidden: true}
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MMG.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions
I really appreciate that 
But unfortunately these doesn't help in in attaining my required result 
issue still stands
typeError: rowObject.properties is undefined number=rowObject.properties.number

Comment: @MMG: You should include more details (`datatype` and the example of input data for the grid for at least two rows) about what you do.

Comment: I had mentioned my datatype as JSON in the first line of my question and as for the data I didn't found a reason for adding the sample data.I can add the sample data as well

Comment: @MMG: **the example of input data which you use is really requited**.

Comment: I have added that as well 
Please take a look @Oleg

Comment: @MMG: You should replace `jsonReader` value to `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false }`, replace the `name` property of all columns of `colModel` which have `.` in the way like I suggested, add `jsonmap` and remove `jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'local'});` from `loadComplete`.

Comment: @MMG: Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MMG.htm). It works. You should use the jsonReader like I posted in my previous comment (**usage of `root: "properties"` inside is wrong for your data**). I modified the code of `Details` column a little to make it working with local data too.

Comment: can you tell me wats the wrong with the scenario or data?
because the solution you have given is not working for me 
Instead it modifies the data in the grid as well

Comment: @MMG: You need compare your code with the code of my demo. Is my demo work on your computer? You can open context menu and then choose "View Page source" (or something like that) to see full HTML/JavaScript code of the demo. Read careful the code of custom formatter. I saved *your demo data* in [MMG.json](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MMG.json) file which I use in the demo. So I use *your data* and practically your code. You need compare your original code and your original data with from my demo and find the error in your code yourself.

Comment: I'm looking into that
Thanks alot for the help

Comment: @MMG: You are welcome! Do you've seen [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25918956/315935) on your previous question? It's very simple to implement call of predefined formatter like "currency" inside of custom formatter.

Comment: Actually i had found the answer before and had forgot to post the answer
thanks for that as well :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365779/jqgrid-showcol-hidecol-not-working-after-sorting[link]
Could you help me with this???