# jqGrid showCol/hideCol not working after sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

The below given code illustrates what I have done fro hide/show. It does work on load but wouldn't work after sorting

```
grid.jqGrid({
    url: "processing.php",
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "POST",
    postData: { "sessionTicket": "<?php echo $sessionTicket; ?>" },
    colNames: ["Details", "Name", "Address", "Date"],
    colModel: [
        {
            id: "details", name: "Details", width: 200, classes: 'pointer wrap',
            formatter: function matterFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                if (rowObject.properties == undefined) {
                    name = rowObject.name;
                    address = rowObject.address;
                } else {
                    name = rowObject.properties.name;
                    address = rowObject.properties.address;
                }
                details = '<strong> ' + name + '</strong> </br><strong> ' + address + '</strong>';
                return details;
            }, sorttype: function (cell, obj) {
                name = obj.name;
                return name;
            }
        },
        { name: "name", jsonmap: "properties.name", width: 200, classes: 'pointer wrap', hidden: true },
        { name: "address", jsonmap: "properties.address", width: 100, classes: 'wrap' },
        { name: "date", jsonmap: "properties.3", width: 55, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'u', newformat: 'd M Y' }, sortable: true, sorttype: 'date' }
    ],
    pager: "#pager",
    //rowNum: 20,
    rowNum: 100,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    sortname: "matter",
    sortorder: 'asc',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    loadonce: true,
    autoencode: true,
    height: 'auto',
    hidegrid: false,
    caption: "Details",
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false
    },
    loadComplete: function () {
        $("#list").setCaption('Jqgrid   <input type="button" id="chooseField" value="Select Fields"  title="Click to Select Fields" />');
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .html('<form id="myform" >' +
            '<input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" value="selectAll" onClick="allField()" /><strong><label for="selectAll">Select All</label></strong><br />' +
            '<input type="checkbox" id="details" value="details" checked /><label for="details">Details</label><br />' +
            '<input type="checkbox" id="name" value="name" checked /><label for="name">Name</label><br />' +
            '<input type="checkbox" id="address" value="address" checked/><label for="address" checked>Address</label><br />' +
            '<input type="checkbox" id="date" value="date" checked/><label for="date" checked>Date</label><br />' +
            '</form>')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Select Fields ',
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            position: [2, 28],
            buttons: {
                "OK": function () { field(); $(this).dialog("close"); },
                "Cancel": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
            }
        });

        $('#chooseField').click(function () {
            $dialog.dialog('open');
            return false;
        });

        $('form#myform').submit(function () {
            $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked') == true) {
                    alert($(this).val());
                }
            })
        });
    }
});

function field() {
    if ($('#Details').is(':checked') == true) {
        $('#list').showCol('Details');
    } else {
        $('#list').hideCol('Details');
    }

    if ($('#name').is(':checked') == true) {
        $('#list').showCol('name');
    } else {
        $('#list').hideCol('name');
    }

    if ($('#address').is(':checked') == true) {
        $('#list').showCol('address');
    } else {
        $('#list').hideCol('address');
    }

    if ($('#date').is(':checked') == true) {
        $('#list').showCol('date');
    } else {
        $('#list').hideCol('date');
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated . I hope this would be a minor tweak would be excellent if someone could help me out in this 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there anyone who could answer this??

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but what you expect with posting of such code? It looks like you get it from the garbage. It's not polite to the readers!

Nevertheless the code have clear at least two problems:

1. creating of dialog inside of `loadComplete` which will be executed **multiple times** (for example after sorting, paging and so on. It seems that you should move the code and place it after the grid is created. In the same way one need to bind `$('#chooseField').click(...)` and `$('form#myform').submit(...)` **once** and not every time on executing `loadComplete`.
2. you use `id` attributes in the `<form>` which are the same as the `name` properties in the `colModel`. It could follow problems with id duplicates if you would use form editing for example. It seems to me that you can rewrite the code of form and binding to checkboxes without usage and `id` attributes at all.

Comment: thanks for those tips Oleg Highly appreciate it 
I didnt  by anyway mean to offend the readers by posting that question. I was in the middle of trying out all the possible ways to fix it. But making those changes you have mentioned doesn't necessarily fix the issue I'm facing. Is there any quick fix in terms of that ?? I tried changing in onsortcol as well :(

Comment: @Gotham'sReckoning: The usage of `onSortCol` will don't help here. Probably I express me not clear enough. After creating the grid the `loadComplete` will be executed at the first time. `<body>` of the page will be appended with `<div class="ui-dialog ...">...</div>`. The `<div>` will contain `<form id="myform">` which contains checkboxes with ids `Details`, `name`,.... On sorting, paging and so on the `loadComplete` will be **executed more and more**. So your code will append `<body>` with the same dialog div with the same contain and the same ids. **You will have id duplicates**!!!

Comment: @Gotham'sReckoning: So you *have to* move the whole code from `loadComplete` in outside of jqGrid.